# using multi prefix in one route

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a project with symfony 3.4. I want to multi route in `app/cofing/routing.yml`

in other words.
I have a route for my bundle like this:

```
custom_panel:
    resource: "@CustomPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

can I have other prefix for api in this route? I mean:

```
custom_panel:
    resource: "@CustomPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /api/v1/users/
```

Comment: What would happen if you try to use that second prefix additionally to the first one?

Comment: can I use multi perfix in one route? 
for example : prefix / and perfix /api

Comment: Have you tried using it?

Comment: actually I have a panel and web api too. I don't want to use another bundle. I want to use two different prefix for those. I don't know. it is a good way or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "good way or not"? Either it works and suits your requirements, or it does not work

Answer (score 0):

In future there may be a possibility to use route aliases, but for now i dont think there is a standard way. But I dont see why you want such a solution? Your route has to have unique name otherwise it will be overwritten by later one.
Why just dont name it differently for example api_custom_panel?

```
api_custom_panel:
    resource: "@CustomPanelBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /api/v1/users/
```